# Developer tools, browser mode - setting IE7 and IE8 simulateneously for different windows

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Is it possible to have two windows of IE8, one in IE8 browser mode and another one in IE7? When I work with IE, I don't want all my windows to be affected when I change the mode to test a specific page in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

`IETester is a free WebBrowser  that allows you to have the rendering and javascript engines of IE8, IE7 IE 6 and IE5.5 on Windows 7, Vista and XP, as well as the installed IE in the same process.`

Comment: I've used this a lot and, although early version could be flakey, it is VERY handy when testing multiple versions of IE.

Comment: I know about IETester, however this is not exactly what I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but you should be able to do it with [maxthon](http://www.maxthon.com/) (using the split view) and a [plugin](http://addons.maxthon.com/en_US/post/2567).